# How to handle multiple post requests at the same time while saving one of them on the db?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am getting n post requests (on each webhook trigger) from a webhook. The data is identical on all requests that come from the same trigger - they all have the same 'orderId'. I'm interested in saving only one of these requests, so on each endpoint hit I'm checking if this specific orderId exists as a row in my database, otherwise - create it.

```
if (await orderIdExists === null) {
                await Order.create(
                    {
                        userId,
                        status: PENDING,
                        price,
                        ...
                    }
                );
                await sleep(3000)
                function sleep(ms) {
                    return new Promise((resolve) => {
                        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
                    });
                }
            }
            return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send({success: true})
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send({success: false})
        }
    }
    else {
        return res.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).send(responseBuilder(false, responseErrorCodes.INVALID_API_KEY, {}, req.t));
    }

}
```

Problem is before Sequelize manages to save the new created order in the db (all of the n post requests get to the enpoint in 1 sec - or less), I already get another endpoint hit from the other n post requests, while orderIdExists still equels null, So it ends up creating more identical orders. One (not so good solution) is to make orderId unique in the db, which prevents the creation of on order with the same orderId, but tries to anyway, which results in empty id incrementation in the db. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.
p.s. as you can see, i tried adding a 'sleep' function to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your database is failing to complete its save operation before the next request arrives. The problem is similar to the [Dogpile Effect](https://www.sobstel.org/blog/preventing-dogpile-effect/) or a "cache slam".

This requires some more thinking about how you are framing the problem: in other words the "solution" will be more philosophical and perhaps have less to do with code, so your results on StackOverflow may vary.

The "sleep" solution is no solution at all: there's no guarantee how long the database operation might take or how long you might wait before another duplicate request arrives.  As a rule of thumb, any time "sleep" is deployed as a "solution" to problems of concurrency, it usually is the wrong choice.

Let me posit two possible ways of dealing with this:

**Option 1:** write-only: i.e. don't try to "solve" this by reading from the database before you write to it. Just keep the pipeline leading into the database as dumb as possible and keep writing.  E.g. consider a "logging" table that just stores whatever the webhook throws at it -- don't try to read from it, just keep inserting (or upserting).  If you get 100 ping-backs about a specific order, so be it: your table would log it all and if you end up with 100 rows for a single `orderId`, let some other downstream process worry about what to do with all that duplicated data.  Presumably, Sequelize is smart enough (and your database supports whatever process locking) to queue up the operations and deal with write repetitions.

An `upsert` operation here would be helpful if you do want to have a unique constraint on the `orderId` (this seems sensible, but you may be aware of other considerations in your particular setup).

**Option 2:** use a queue.  This is decidedly more complex, so weigh carefully wether or not your use-case justifies the extra work.  Instead of writing data immediately to the database, throw the webhook data into a queue (e.g. a first-in-first-out FIFO queue).  Ideally, you would want to choose a queue that supports de-duplication so that exiting messages are guaranteed to be unique, but that infers state, and that usually relies on a database of some sort, which is sort of the problem to begin with.

The most important thing a queue would do for you is it would serialize the messages so you can deal with them one at a time (instead of multiple database operations kicking off concurrently). You can upsert data into the database when you read a message out of the queue.  If the webhook keeps firing and more messages enter the queue, that's fine because the queue forces them all to line up single-file and you can handle each insertion one at a time. You'll know that each database operation has completed before it moves on to the next message so you never "slam" the DB. In other words, putting a queue in front of the database will allow it to handle data *when the database is ready* instead of whenever a webhook comes calling.

The idea of a queue here is similar to what a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) accomplishes. Note that your database interface may already implement a kind of queue/pool under-the-hood, so weigh this option carefully: don't reinvent a wheel.

Hope those ideas are useful.

Comment: Thanks so much, they are indeed very useful! One question though, how can I implement the queue if each http request is stateless? i.e. how will it 'know' the previous requests and store them all in a queue?

Comment: Some queues preserve state (sometimes by being backed by a DATABASE, albeit maybe a _faster_ database). The tool to preserve state in most dev scenarios is a database, so even if the queue does nothing but sequentialize the messages, that allows the database to deal with them one at a time and that should mean that it can properly check the state (i.e. if the row exists) one message at a time.  In other words, this is a place where you _don't want concurrency_: you want to deal with the messages one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You saved my time @Everett and @april-henig. I found that saving directly into database read to records duplicates. If you store records into an object and deal with one record at time helped me a lot.
May be I would share my solution perhaps some may find it useful in future.

#### Create an empty object to save success request

```js
export const queueAllSuccessCallBack = {};
```

#### Save `POST` request in object

```js
    if (status === 'success') { // I checked the request if is only successfully
      const findKeyTransaction = queueAllSuccessCallBack[client_reference_id];
      if (!findKeyTransaction) { // check if Id is not added to avoid any duplicates
        queueAllSuccessCallBack[client_reference_id] = {
          transFound,
          body,
        }; // save new request id as key and the value as data you want
      }
    }
```

#### Access the object to save into database

```js
   const keys = Object.keys(queueAllSuccessCallBack);
   keys.forEach(async (key) => {
     ...  
     // Do extra checks if you want to do so
    // Or save in database direct
   });
```